# Flutter text field value from state + on change update state

Tags: flutter, state

I have a text field value powered by a State variable with some calculation, I want to live calculate and update the same state variable back when user inputs value. The final result just doesnt work, text fiend input behaves strangely.

If I use onSubmitted instead of onChanged, it works well, I guess I am not in a loop of updating values back and forth from the state variable.

Any idea how can I make this happen?

```
myController.text = '${value.toStringAsFixed(1)}';

TextField(
  onChanged: (text){
    this.onValueChange(text, index);
  },
  controller: myController,
),
```

and the function onValueChange is calling to set state is this

```
  void setValue(_value, _index){
    setState((){
      value =double.parse(_value)/exchangeRate["rates"][currencies[_index]];
    });
  }
```

Comment: still same, the text input behaves strangely, some time delete doesnt work, and the cursor pops around the number..

Comment: I don't understand what you said about the loop. Are you updating the same text on the field that you're writing on?

Comment: yes, I am using the text field to display the value and also allows the user to edit it, the new value will then be saved to state.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we want to make a textfieild for OTP and submit button press once on that it display the OTP on console screen and we fill that our text field same as console

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

add listener to get the text field value

```
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  // update value in listener
  myController.addListener(() {
  setState(() {
    myController.text = "your value";
  });
});
}

// your textField

TextField(
 controller: myController,
),
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use `setState` inside `onChanged`

```
TextField(
  onChanged: (text){
    setState(() {
      this.onValueChange(text, index);
    });
  },
  controller: myController,
),
```